# How to add resource files to CefSharp.Wpf as string

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium, cefsharp

I have a C# WPF Project, in which i want to display a Web View with Chromium CefSharp.WPF.

The Content of the WebView should be loaded from a SQL database.

I already can display a html page with `LoadHtml(html, url)`.

But how can I load resourcefiles (styles or scripts) as string?

Example: `LoadResource(data, "./styles.css")`

Comment: if I correctly understood, you have resource file and want to load this as string. So what `data` is?

Comment: Correctly. data is a string variable which contains e.g. the content of a stylesheet. "body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
}"

Comment: Look at the source for `LoadHtml`, it's just an extension method, you can register additional resources without loading them. Or implement your own `scheme`, there are examples of that in the project source also. Check `GitHub`.

Comment: Oh, thanks! LoadHtml just register a scheme and load the url. I just need to register them. that´s great!